# How to use do_shortcode_tag to modify the output of a shortcode?

Tags: filters, shortcode

I would like to add shortcodes whose content gets processed by plugins before it gets displayed in the page.

In particular, I have a plugin which processes content between two $ signs to produce math formulas and graphs.
A simple shortcode is

```
add_shortcode( 'test', 'test_sc' );
function test_sc( $atts ){ return "$\frac{15}{5} = 3$"; }
```

By writing `$\frac{15}{5} = 3$` in a page this gets displayed [image]

By writing `[test]` in a page this gets displayed `$\frac{15}{5} = 3$`

WordPress does a few things before the content from a page or post gets displayed on the site. For instance, it processes HTML paragraph (p) tags, it runs shortcodes and even sends the content to the theme and any plugins so they can do their thing to the content and include their bits.

I heard that using `do_shortcode_tag` ([reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/do_shortcode_tag/)) it is possibile to do full content processing, but how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a LaTex plugin? It probably filters "the_content". Try

`return apply_filters( 'the_content', '$\frac{15}{5} = 3$' );`

Comment: thanks, yes it is quicklatex plugin, now i try your code

Comment: it works! a small problem is that the shortcode content is displayed inside `<p>` tags, and so if i write `this is [test] a fraction` it gets displayed in 3 lines (the first one contains `this is`, the second one contains the formula, the third one contains `a fraction`). Is it possible to show it without them? thank you!

Comment: maybe we have to use `remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );` ?

Comment: there is also `shortcode_unautop`

Comment: wpautop just adds paragraph tags. wptexturize might alter other things, like quotes.

Comment: i dont understand, the content is wrapped inside `p` tags, im trying to remove them.  tried many codes (such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940854/disable-automatic-formatting-inside-wordpress-shortcodes) and the plugin `Shortcode Empty Paragraph Fix` but none worked.

Comment: strange thing is that if i add `remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );` to `functions.php` file, nothing happens

Comment: Does remove_all_filters( 'the_content' ) work?
Remember to remove the filter late, like in 'init' or even 'wp_loaded'. Just removing when functions.php are loaded will not work, as not all filters are added yet.

Comment: i placed `remove_all_filters( 'the_content' )` inside the functions.php file, but then this error showed when reloading the site`The site is experiencing technical difficulties.`. Where are the files `init` and `wp_loaded` located? Have i to place the code in those files?

Comment: 1) You need to always end all statements with a ; even if I forgot it in my comment. 

2) Not other files, but actions determine _when_ something should happen:
`add_action( 'wp_loaded', function() {
    remove_all_filters( 'the_content' );
} );`

Comment: Ah right thanks i added the semicolon and the errors vanished. By writing `remove_all_filters( 'the_content' );` the content of she shortcode is not displayed anymore, simply `[test]` is displayed instead. By writing `add_action( 'wp_loaded', function() { remove_all_filters( 'the_content' ); } );` it happens the same plus other math formulas in the page outside the shortcode are not displayed anymore (the code of the equations is displayed instead).

Comment: Then remove just wpautop.

Comment: is it possibile to remove wpautop just for the shortcodes? because wpautop is handy in other cases